# How would i instantiate and pass a 2d array to a method?

Tags: java, arrays

So in my code i have a constructor that is supposed to take two 2d arrays and a enum of a quadrant i already have set up. I have set up my constructor like this.

```
public ThreadOperation(int[][] a, int[][] b, Quadrants x){
    
    }
```

I have instantiated a new object that looks like this

```
ThreadOperation T1 = new ThreadOperation(int[][],int[][],Quadrants.TopLeft);
```

i keep getting the error error: '.class' expected.
Im new to programming so i guess im just having trouble trying to figure out how to pass the two 2d arrays over to the constructor without giving me an error. These are just placeholders so i can compile.

Comment: `int[][]` by itself does not create and initialize a 2D array of `int`. `int[][] array = new int[10][10];`, for example, does (filling it with the desired values is left as an exercise for the reader). And then you can use `array`, or however you call your array, as a parameter.

Comment: Okay i believe i see what you mean. I created two example arrays and instead of what i had i changed it to  new ThreadOperation(matrix1,matrix2,Quadrants.TopLeft);

Comment: With the modification, do you still get an error?

Answer (score 1):

check this out , you would need to initialise :-

```
public class Operation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][]a = new int[2][2];
        int [][]b = new int[3][3];
        TestMe testMe = new TestMe(a,b,Month.January);
    }
}
class TestMe {
    int [][] a;
    int [][] b;
    Month month;

    public TestMe(int[][] a, int[][] b, Month month) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.month = month;
    }
}

enum Month {
    January
}
```